# tar --from-files, does not interpret hyphen at beginning of a filename

Tags: tar

We are using tar 1.26 on CentOS 7.9 and I'm trying to untar an archive that has files in it which begin with a hyphen.

I tell tar through `--files-from` which files I want to extract, since I don't want to extract everything.

For that I have the file `filelist.txt` with the following content
`-myfile.txt`

Calling tar like `tar -xmf mytar.tar --no-wildcards --files-from filelist.txt` causes tar to error with the following error

```
tar: invalid option -- 'y'
```

This is because tar interprets the starting hyphen as an argument for tar (I assume)
I already added `--no-wildcards` to disable pattern matching.

Is there any possibility to disable this behavior or better yet tell tar to take every entry from `filelist.txt` literally without trying match/interpret anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If upgrading to version 1.29 or greater of GNU `tar` is an option, the `--verbatim-files-from` switch provides the feature you seem to be looking for. Quoting the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

> `--verbatim-files-from`
> Treat each line obtained from a file list as a file name, even if it starts with a dash. File lists are supplied with the `--files-from` (`-T`) option. The default behavior is to handle names supplied in file lists as if they were typed in the command line,  i.e. any names starting with a dash are treated as `tar` options.  The `--verbatim-files-from` option disables this behavior.

Unfortunately, `--verbatim-files-from` is not available in GNU `tar` 1.26.